# submit button not sending form data jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

so facing some problem while sending form data to my mail account.
Basically i am using script code containing basic form with two fields name and email when i send my data through form it didn't respond.
Here is my script code

```
  <script>
;(function($){
$.fn.forms=function(o){
    return this.each(function(){
        var th=$(this)
            ,_=th.data('forms')||{
                errorCl:'error',
                emptyCl:'empty',
                invalidCl:'invalid',
                notRequiredCl:'notRequired',
                successCl:'success',
                successShow:'4000',
                mailHandlerURL:'bin/MailHandler.php',
                ownerEmail:'samraiqbal18@gmail.com',
                stripHTML:true,
                smtpMailServer:'localhost',
                targets:'input,textarea',
                controls:'a[data-type=reset],a[data-type=submit]',
                validate:true,
                rx:{
                    ".name":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                    ".state":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                    ".email":{rx:/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i,target:'input'},
                    ".phone":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                    ".fax":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                    ".message":{rx:/.{20}/,target:'textarea'}
                },
                preFu:function(){
                    _.labels.each(function(){
                        var label=$(this),
                            inp=$(_.targets,this),
                            defVal=inp.val(),
                            trueVal=(function(){
                                        var tmp=inp.is('input')?(tmp=label.html().match(/value=['"](.+?)['"].+/),!!tmp&&!!tmp[1]&&tmp[1]):inp.html()
                                        return defVal==''?defVal:tmp
                                    })()
                        trueVal!=defVal
                            &&inp.val(defVal=trueVal||defVal)
                        label.data({defVal:defVal})                             
                        inp
                            .bind('focus',function(){
                                inp.val()==defVal
                                    &&(inp.val(''),_.hideEmptyFu(label),label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                            })
                            .bind('blur',function(){
                                _.validateFu(label)
                                if(_.isEmpty(label))
                                    inp.val(defVal)
                                    ,_.hideErrorFu(label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))                                          
                            })
                            .bind('keyup',function(){
                                label.hasClass(_.invalidCl)
                                    &&_.validateFu(label)
                            })
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl+',.'+_.emptyCl).css({display:'block'}).hide()
                    })
                    _.success=$('.'+_.successCl,_.form).hide()
                },
                isRequired:function(el){                            
                    return !el.hasClass(_.notRequiredCl)
                },
                isValid:function(el){                           
                    var ret=true
                    $.each(_.rx,function(k,d){
                        if(el.is(k))
                            ret=d.rx.test(el.find(d.target).val())                                      
                    })
                    return ret                          
                },
                isEmpty:function(el){
                    var tmp
                    return (tmp=el.find(_.targets).val())==''||tmp==el.data('defVal')
                },
                validateFu:function(el){                            
                    el.each(function(){
                        var th=$(this)
                            ,req=_.isRequired(th)
                            ,empty=_.isEmpty(th)
                            ,valid=_.isValid(th)                                

                        if(empty&&req)
                            _.showEmptyFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))
                        else
                            _.hideEmptyFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))

                        if(!empty)
                            if(valid)
                                _.hideErrorFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                            else
                                _.showErrorFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))                             
                    })
                },
                getValFromLabel:function(label){
                    var val=$('input,textarea',label).val()
                        ,defVal=label.data('defVal')                                
                    return label.length?val==defVal?'nope':val:'nope'
                }
                ,submitFu:function(){
                    _.validateFu(_.labels)                          
                    if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url:_.mailHandlerURL,
                            data:{
                                name:_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form)),
                                email:_.getValFromLabel($('.email',_.form)),
                                phone:_.getValFromLabel($('.phone',_.form)),
                                fax:_.getValFromLabel($('.fax',_.form)),
                                state:_.getValFromLabel($('.state',_.form)),
                                message:_.getValFromLabel($('.message',_.form)),
                                owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
                                stripHTML:_.stripHTML
                            },
                            success: function(){
                                _.showFu()
                            }
                        })          
                },
                showFu:function(){
                    _.success.slideDown(function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            _.success.slideUp()
                            _.form.trigger('reset')
                        },_.successShow)
                    })
                },
                controlsFu:function(){
                    $(_.controls,_.form).each(function(){
                        var th=$(this)
                        th
                            .bind('click',function(){
                                _.form.trigger(th.data('type'))
                                return false
                            })
                    })
                },
                showErrorFu:function(label){
                    label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideDown()
                },
                hideErrorFu:function(label){
                    label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideUp()
                },
                showEmptyFu:function(label){
                    label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideDown()
                    _.hideErrorFu(label)
                },
                hideEmptyFu:function(label){
                    label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideUp()
                },
                init:function(){
                    _.form=_.me                     
                    _.labels=$('label',_.form)

                    _.preFu()

                    _.controlsFu()

                    _.form
                        .bind('submit',function(){
                            if(_.validate)
                                _.submitFu()
                            else
                                _.form[0].submit()
                            return false
                        })
                        .bind('reset',function(){
                            _.labels.removeClass(_.invalidCl)                                   
                            _.labels.each(function(){
                                var th=$(this)
                                _.hideErrorFu(th)
                                _.hideEmptyFu(th)
                            })
                        })
                    _.form.trigger('reset')
                }
            }
        _.me||_.init(_.me=th.data({forms:_}))
        typeof o=='object'
            &&$.extend(_,o)
    })
}
})(jQuery)

$(function(){$('#contact-form').forms({ownerEmail:'#'});});

</script>
```

And below is my simple html /css code for form

```
<form id="contact-form" >
    <div class="success"> Contact form submitted! <strong>We will be in touch soon.</strong></div>
    <fieldset class="fieldclass" >
        <label class="name">
            <input type="text" id="placeid" placeholder="Name">
            <span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span>
            <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
            <span class="clear"></span>
        </label>
        <br><br>
        <label class="email">
            <input type="text" id="placeid" placeholder ="E-mail">
            <span class="error">*This is not a valid email address.</span>
            <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
            <span class="clear"></span>
        </label>

        <div class="buttons">
            <span id="resetbtn">
                <a class="button" data-type="reset">reset</a>
            </span>
            <span id="submitbtn">
                <a class="button" data-type="submit">submit</a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you debug your code and inspect data before calling the ajax method?

Comment: yeah i check it says Uncaught TypeError: $(...).navs is not a function
 at n (jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith (jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.B (jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2

Comment: here is the screen shot too http://prntscr.com/fjixul
hope it will help

Comment: Please create a demo of your code on jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: what you want exactly in this case??

Comment: https://codepen.io/samra18/project/editor/ZvYJjG/ via @CodePen

Comment: you have probably problem with $('.bgslider-nav').navs() in script.js
$('.bgslider-nav') is undefined or method navs does not exists... if it fails on this line executing  other js lines wont be executed.

Comment: ok so i slove the above issue but now he show something like this
http://prntscr.com/fjrmhd